# Lxml trying to extract data with windows-1250 characters

Tags: python, lxml

Hello i am experimenting with Python and LXML, and I am stuck with the problem of extracting data from the webpage which contains windows-1250 characters like ž and ć.

```
tree = html.fromstring(new.text,parser=hparser)
title = tree.xpath('//strong[text()="Title"]')
opis[g] = opis[g].tail.encode('utf-8')[2:]
```

I get text responses containing something like this :

```
\xc2\x9ea
```

instead of characters. Then I have the problem with storing into database

So how can I accomplish this? I tried put 'windows-1250' instead utf8 without success. Can I convert this code to original characters somehow?

Comment: are all the charcters like that? you might want to [decode the windows-1250](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801953/python-2-7-encoding-decoding) characters

Comment: no, only some characters. if i try to decode i get error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: see the link in the previous comment for how to decode

Comment: @Vikast `\xc2\x9ea` when converted from UTF-8 is simply `u'\u009ea'`, which is almost certainly not what you want (it's unlikely that an HTML page would need ["U+009E PRIVACY MESSAGE"](https://codepoints.net/U+009E?lang=en).) Unfortunately for you, when converted from CP1250, it maps byte-for-byte to `Âža`. I'd recommend opening the file in a hex editor and ensuring that the sequence `C2 9E 61` does not appear at the location where `ža` (`9E 61`) occurs. Otherwise, you have a problem with your file's encoding. The proper UTF-8 encoding of `ža` is `C5 BE 61`, so UTF-8 isn't the correct encoding

Comment: Do you have a `<meta>` tag with the character set declared? What is the specified character encoding? Alternatively, what character encoding does your browser detect? Does the problem occur in a new file containing the characters that are causing you difficulty?

Comment: after i do this    opis[g] = opis[g].tail.encode('utf-8')[2:]     then with opis[g].decode("windows-1250").encode("utf-8") , i can get desired result but there is weird characters like Â appended before ž .

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
text = "\xc2\x9ea"
print text.decode('windows-1250').encode('utf-8')
```

**Output**:

```
Âža
```

And save nice chars in your DB.

Comment: Hey i get this additional Â before those characters, how can i remove this Â?

Comment: Well, it is part of the response. **\xc2** = Â,  **x9e** = ž, **a** = a

Comment: your code is working but, it always add additional characters like Â before those characters so i get "PlaÂža" for example

Comment: Do you want to get only this characters? **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789**

Comment: those plus ž,ć,š,đ . its for croatian lang.

Comment: Just make a **white_list** with the chars I shared above plus the ones you want and then loop through the text checking if each letter belongs to **white_list**. A list comprehension would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If encoding to UTF-8 results in `b'\xc2\x9ea'`, then that means the original string was `'\x9ea'`. Whether lxml didn't do things correctly, or something happened on your end (perhaps a parser configuration issue), the fact is that you get the equivalent of this (Python 3.x syntax):

```
>>> '\x9ea'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x9ea'
```

How do you fix it? One error-prone way would be to encode as something other than UTF-8 that can properly handle the characters. It's error-prone because while something might work in one case, it might not in another. You could instead extract the character ordinals by mapping the character ordinals and work with the character ordinals instead:

```
>>> list(map((lambda n: hex(n)[2:]), map(ord, '\x9ea')))
['9e', '61']
```

That gets us somewhere because the `bytes` type has a `fromhex` method that can decode a string containing hexadecimal values to the equivalent byte values:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(''.join(map((lambda n: hex(n)[2:]), map(ord, '\x9ea'))))
b'\x9ea'
```

You can use `decode('cp1250')` on the result of that to get `ža`, which I believe is the string you wanted. If you are using Python 2.x, the equivalent would be

```
from binascii import unhexlify
unhexlify(u''.join(map((lambda n: hex(n)[2:]), map(ord, u'\x9ea'))))
```

Note that this is highly destructive as it forces all characters in a Unicode string to be interpreted as bytes. For this reason, it should only be used on strings containing Unicode characters that fit in a single byte. If you had something like `'\x9e\u724b\x61'`, that code would result in joining `['9e', '724b', '61']` as `'9e724b61'`, and interpreting that using a single-byte character set such as CP1250 would result in something like `'žrKa'`.

For that reason, more reliable code would replace `ord` with a function that throws an exception if `0 <= ord(ch) < 0x100` is false, but I'll leave that for you to code.